# xamarin android best practises to tables with multiple columns

Tags: android, xamarin

Maybe its a easy question but i cant figure out how to do tables with multiple columns and rows.. Order data in this table will be get via wcf service and next present in table. In this table i need of course scrolling and filtering. Every row will link in to details about order.
I thinking about using table layout and put in lists but this not resolved my problem with scrolling.. So should i do this? Which is best practise in this case topics?
I attach picture with this table.
Thanks for help.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found solution of this problem on xamarin forum.
If samebody have better idea it will be pleasure to hear it.. :)
[XamarinForum](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15231/multi-column-listview-bind-class-list)